# what is best config for csf about synflood but web response still fast

Tags: nginx, firewall

my server down random every day 4-5 time cause get high load very quick..

I have install csf and with some config server now stable.. load around 5.

BUT the big isuse is : the real user very hard to access website specially from IE browser you can test at xaluan.com, it also timeout some time.

the flowing is config using in csf:

```
SYNFLOOD = "1"
SYNFLOOD_RATE = "100/s"
SYNFLOOD_BURST = "10"

CONNLIMIT = "80;30"
PORTFLOOD = "80;tcp;70;5"
CT_LIMIT = "29"
```

other config may same as default

i playing around with this config for a week but still not good..

If increase the rate up to SYNFLOOD_RATE = "140/s" or more.. the website response very fast.. only bad side effect of server load increase so fast, normal 20 and may be up to few hundred in peak time ..

my need is response time fast but load still low.. please help

thanks

ps: server runing nginx frontend, apache, mysql, php ,, the home page has around 70 elements which will cached in browser in fist time access..

Answer (score 1):

> my server down random every day 4-5 time cause get high load very quick

There can be many reasons for this. try    nice top -c -d 2    from command line and check what process is causing too much load. You can't simply blame csf for that.

Load may get high if the DB disk I/O is high. Its better to install mytop DB monitoring tool in the server and check if that the reason.

For installing mytop use this link http://bloke.org/linux/installing-mytop-on-cpanel/

I hope this will help you to monitor DB load usage